# Is the sentence correct (with a participle)?

Tags: participles

I have the following sentence:

"The operation of washing machines can be shifted in time, **making** their electrical loads deferrable"

Can I use the paticiple 'making' here?

Comment: The sentence would still be awkward, and could be rephrased as, perhaps, "The washing machine has a timer so that it can operate out of peak demand."

Comment: Yes, your sentence is grammatically correct.